# Is there any AMS TeX or LaTeX macro for background color in math-mode

Tags: color, amsmath

Is there any way to display math expressions with a background color (highlight) using [AMS-Tex](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amstex) or [AMS-LaTeX](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex) . For example, using AMS-TeX/LaTeX, we can display a math expression in font color using `\color[colorName]{mathExpression}`.

**UPDATE** Using the answer from @werner, I tried `$\frac{\colorbox{yellow}{$a-b$}}{c-d}$` to highlight only the numerator but the size of `a-b` is much larger than the demominator `c-d` even with the setting of `\setlength{\fboxsep}{1pt}` -in the preamble - as shown below. How can I get the desired output shown below:

[image]

Comment: If you load [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor), you can use `\colorbox{<color>}{$<math content>$}`. This uses a regular "framed box", so you can set the values of `\fboxsep` to decrease the border.

Comment: ams-tex is plain-based, not latex, so although it's feasible to concoct a method to include color, it's not trivial, and i don't know of any package that might do it.  ams-latex, on the other hand, is based (as its name implies) on latex, so @Werner's suggestion is one good possibility.

Comment: @Werner, thank you for providing this information. I thought \colorbox command is only for highlighting plain text in color. For example, \colorbox{yellow}{x^3} would highlight the plain text x^3 in yellow and not in math-mode as ‘x cubed’. Whereas, the font color command, e.g., \color{yellow}{x^3} would display ‘x cubed’ in math-mode with yellow font.  Now, I know that, for \colorbox, we need to enclose the math expression with delimiter such as \colorbox{yellow}{$x^3$}.

Comment: @nam: I've converted my comment into an answer, since it seemed to have satisfied your requirements.

Comment: @Werner, sorry I did not know at that time about marking a response as an answer. I have marked it as an answer now.

Comment: @Werner I've added an **UPDATE** section in my original post with a question in regard to your answer. Using your solution how can I get the output shown in the UPDATE section.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you load [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor), you can use `\colorbox`. This uses a regular "framed box", so you can set the values of `\fboxsep` to decrease the border.

In most cases, text-related formatting of this sort also transfers to math-related content. However, a verbatim switch is sometimes required since boxing reverts back to text mode. As such, use

```
\colorbox{<color>}{$<math content>$}
```

and *not*

```
$\colorbox{<color>}{<math content>}$
```

---

Here's a small example in LaTeX illustrating the use of `\colorbox` together with a modification of `\fboxsep`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
Here is \colorbox{blue!50}{coloured text} with a coloured \colorbox{green!30}{$f(x)$} function. \par \bigskip
\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}% No "border" around coloured box
Here is \colorbox{blue!50}{coloured text} with a coloured \colorbox{green!30}{$f(x)$} function. \par
\end{document}
```

Comment: herbert voss wrote a good summary -- which may be read from CTAN [MathCol](mathCol)  which is pretty clear (even to non-readers of german) sinc http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathCol/mathCol.pdf since all the examples come with source+typeset output.

Comment: i find writing in this sort of medium very difficult.  have to find all my typos within 5 minutes; failed with my previous own afaict).  anyway, the link should be [mathCol](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathCol/mathCol.pdf)