# Using background color in AMSmath

Tags: color, amsmath

I'm using `\(\frac{\colorbox{yellow}{a-b}}{c-d}\)` to highlight numerator only. But (as suggested in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86210/22810)) how do we use `\colorbox{<color>}{\(<math content>\)}` format to achieve the same. I want only the numerator to be highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Using package amstext, you can write:

```
$\frac{\text{\colorbox{yellow}{$a-b$}}}{c-d}$
```

Comment: But that output does _not_ match `$\frac{a-b}{c-d}$`.

Comment: @user94293 I compared your output with mine in TeXWorks editor. Your output is better than `$\frac{\colorbox{yellow}{a-b}}{c-d}$` but, as Peter indicated, still does not match the output of `$\frac{a-b}{c-d}$`

Comment: Add \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt} to remove the unnecessary blank around the numerator